# JavaScript Countdown program

Tags: javascript

im trying to write a program in JavaScript that fulfils this prompt

Write a JavaScript function
countDown(i)
that takes an integer argument and returns a \countdown" from i to 0, with a space appearing between
each number.
For example, countDown(5) should return the string "5 4 3 2 1 0". As for the rst problem, you may
want to test your solution on the computer.

sofar I have this

```
var i= "";

function countdown(i)

{

    while( i > 0)

    {
        console.log(integer);
        i--;
    }
}
countdown();
```

can someone please help me im very new to programing

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript

Comment: I assume this is some kind of homework and you want a commented and explained answer?

Comment: Careful, `i` is string but you're using it as number. Problem.

Comment: Change your `var i=""` line to `var i=5;`

Comment: What is the problem, besides having a wrong variable name in the console output: `console.log(integer);` – it should be `console.log(i);` instead…

Comment: Actually, I wouldn't declare i outside the function...

Comment: Actually the `i` he defines through `var i` is "hidden" in the function since the function has a parameter named `i`.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this makes enough sense:

```
function countdown(i) {
    //initialize the variable to be returned with the initial i
    var ret = i;
    //in each iteration, assigns i to i-1 then checks if i >= 0
    while (--i >= 0) {
        //concatenates a space and the current i value to the return string
        ret += ' ' + i;
    }
    //returns the string
    return ret;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/9FeRn/3/)

Answer (score 1):

I hope you read the comments I've put in the code and learn.

```
// you write comments in JavaScript with two forward slashes
// i is the integer parameter of your countdown function
// i is passed to countdown when called, i.e. countdown(9)
function countdown(i)    
{
    // this is an ret string variable that is private to the countdown function
    // you can't access ret from outside of this function
    var ret = "";   

    // your loop should include 0 according to your requirements
    while( i >= 0)
    {
        // here you are appending i to your ret string which you'll return at the end of this function      
        ret += i;// += is a short hand form of saying ret = ret + i

        // you want to append an empty space for every i except the last one (0)
        if(i > 0) {
            ret += " "; 
        }
        i--;    // here you are decrementing i
    }
    return ret;
}
// here you are making the actual call to the function with integer 5 
// you are assigning the returned value of your function call to result variable
var result = countdown(5);  

// here you are printing your result string variable to the log
console.log(result);
```

Here another solution (bit more advanced) using recursion, alternative to for/while loops where a function calls itself:

```
// here is an implementation using recursion
function countdown(i)    
{
    if(i<=0)    
        return i;
    return i + " " + countdown(--i);
}
```

Comment: Once, you understand this, see Fabricio's answer and how he refactors this logic.

Comment: Heh thanks for the mention, I tend to make stuff slightly more complicated than the necessary though. Your comments are very detailed, +1 for the level of detail.

Comment: for some reason the codes you guys gave me dont repeat in the scratch pad they just output the first number i put in

Answer (score 0):

You want to include `0` in your countdown, so you want

```
while (i >= 0)
```

as opposed to `while (i > 0)`, which excludes `0` at the end.

---

Also, as some of the comments mentioned, `var i = ""` defines `i` to be a *string*, so you cannot perform operations like `i--`. You should define `i` to be an integer, e.g. `var i = 5`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
 function countdown(i) {
   answer = '';
   while( i >= 0) {
      answer = answer + i.toString() + ' ';
      i--;
   }
   return answer;
 }

 countdown(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it using recursion:

```
//define countdown function
var countdown = function countdown(i) {
    //loop while the passed in parameter "i" is >= 0
    while (i >= 0) {
        //return a space concatenated with the value of i
        //and call the countdown function again (by
        //concatenating the result) to continue counting down
        return ' ' + i + countdown(i -= 1);
    }
    return ''; //out of loop, return an empty string
};
console.log(countdown(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

recursive way ;)

```
​var countdown=function(i) {
    console.log(i);
    i>0 && countdown(i-1);
}
    countdown(10);
```